Copying event listener of button in JavaScript
I have this problem.
On simple instagram user page there is a Follow button, Message button and three dots button.
I need to copy listener of some button under the three dots, create new button using JS and use the same listener.
Can you please help me copying the listener? When I inspect the website and try to find what does the button do exacly, it looks like it's runing few functions. But I can't simply copy the code into the console.
For example I want to create new button with text "Block" and put it next to the Message button (I can do that on my own), but then make it to do the same thing as if you clicked block in the three dots.
I tried googling but I am probably not good at this enough. I am a begginer, thank you for your help.

The way to achieve that was what I said, since the Instagram uses React, our way is blocked.

@Amirhosein so do you think it's not possible?

as I see it yeah

Now I got what you want!
open inspect->console then select the three dot button using query (or anything else) then we consider that element as id :button now:
document.getElementById('button').onclick

this will return the function you want!
Hope it helps ^_^

you are very close! for some reason instagram's website is wierdly built and it returns empty function. you can try it yourself by going to random user's instagram profile
